# How to fix this error in python "AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'"

Tags: python, pyserial

I am working on a project with arduino Joystick. I am trying to use a joystick for a game and cant figure out how to do it. I copied some code and changed some things but got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Joystick.py", line 4, in <module>
    arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200)
AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'
```

I didnt think anything was wrong i just pip installed pyserial and tried it out and got the error. Have any Idea what could be wrong?

Here is my code:

```
import serial
import pyautogui

arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200)

pyautogui.PAUSE = 0

keysDown = {}

# Element = key to be pressed
# leave empty to not map
keyMap = [  
    ''      # JoyStick button
]

def keyDown(key):
    if key not in keysDown:
        keysDown[key] = True
        pyautogui.keyDown(key)
        # print('Down: ', key)


def keyUp(key):
    if key in keysDown:
        del(keysDown[key])
        pyautogui.keyUp(key)
        # print('Up: ', key)


def handleJoyStickAsArrowKeys(x, y):
    if x > 0:
        keyDown('right')
        keyUp('left')
    elif x < 0:
        keyDown('left')
        keyUp('right')
    else:
        keyUp('left')
        keyUp('right')

    if y > 0:
        keyDown('down')
        keyUp('up')
    elif y < 0:
        keyDown('up')
        keyUp('down')
    else:
        keyUp('up')
        keyUp('down')


def handleButtonState(state):
    for i in range(1):
        if not keyMap[i]:
            continue

        if buttonState >> i & 1:
            keyDown(keyMap[i])
        else:
            keyUp(keyMap[i])


while True:
    data = arduino.read()
    if data == 'S':
        dx = int(arduino.read_until(',')[:-1])
        if abs(dx) < 10:
            dx = 0
        dy = int(arduino.read_until(',')[:-1])
        if abs(dy) < 10:
            dy = 0
        buttonState = int(arduino.readline()[:-2])
        handleJoyStickAsArrowKeys(dx, dy * -1)
        handleButtonState(buttonState)
```

I have tried multiple things and nothing has worked. I am using linux by the way.

Comment: To eliminate an easy one - do you have a file named serial.py that it could be importing instead of the one you intended?

Comment: Can you try **from serial import Serial**